# occurrence of two rows in columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame and i want to count the most common fives pair of two rows in two columns (col_1 col_2)

for instance, the below pair

```
B      C
C      B
```

occurs twice in the table below

```
col_1 col_2 value

A      N    2
N      A    3
B      C    5
C      B    6
S      A    2
A      S    2
B      C    2
C      B    1
```

Comment: Do you have some code we can work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) and get values of index:

```
N = 2
a = df.groupby(['Col_1','col_2']).size().nlargest(N).index.tolist()
print (a)
[('B', 'C'), ('C', 'B')]
```

If need new `DataFrame` use [`MultiIndex.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Col_1','col_2']).size().nlargest(2).index.to_frame(index=False)
print (df1)
  Col_1 col_2
0     B     C
1     C     B
```

If need count all ocurrencies:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Col_1','col_2']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df2)
  Col_1 col_2  count
0     A     N      1
1     A     S      1
2     B     C      2
3     C     B      2
4     N     A      1
5     S     A      1
```